# Co-citation analysis of my library?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics, reference-managers

I just realized that the co-citation analysis is a very handy tool, especially at the initial stage of the research. There are many software available that do the co-citation and bibliographic analysis for you. However, most of them require the output file from scientific search engines like Scopus, Web of Science, and so on.

What I would like to do is to run a co-citation analysis on a collection of scientific papers that I have (gathered in a folder), to see how the citation network looks like and find the most important papers. I am currently using Vosviewer but it appears that it does not allow such analysis.

I have exported the .ris file from Mendeley and then read it in Vosviewer but then it only shows the co-authorship and co-occurrence of keywords, which are not interesting for me.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: This is either a shopping question, if you are looking for a tool, or "not within scope" if you are looking for how to do it. You could write your own tool, of course.

Comment: @Buffy Questions about software tools [are explicitly allowed](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4679/68109).

Comment: Is https://www.connectedpapers.com/ or https://scite.ai/ along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: @0xDBFB7 no because these platforms only allow you to choose a particular paper and see the citation map for it. However, as I mentioned, I am looking for a method to develop the citation network for my library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import your library into [Inciteful.xyz](https://inciteful.xyz/)* or [LitMaps](https://www.litmaps.co/).

---

<sup>* *Note*: So far, *Inciteful.xyz* only supports an import of BibTeX files. However, (1) you can easily [convert .ris files to BibTeX](https://www.bruot.org/ris2bib/), and (2) it seems that *Inciteful.xyz* is still under development and might enable the direct import of .ris files soon ([see this Tweet](https://twitter.com/antlion/status/1412884033357320193)).</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. LitMAps is exactly what I wanted. I created a bib file from my library using Mendeley and supplied it to LitMap, which then made a citation network for me.