# Software tool to identify clusters in academic papers?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics, network-analysis

I know connected papers, web of knowledge, research rabbits, but they all either only seem look at one or a limited amount of papers and visualise new papers related to them.

What I want to do is to upload a list of 300 papers for example, and then show how they are related. Goal is to identify clusters. I have a large number of papers (the "nodes"), but not any metric of similarity between them ("edges"), nor any tool for analyzing  the resulting graph.

My research area is the connection between land use and transport. There are a lot of different lines of research to explore this. I want to identify these "lines".

Comment: I think this sort of thing may be better placed at e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. The topic you're interested in analyzing may be academic data, but you're still asking about how to do *data analysis*.

Comment: @AnonymousM The reason why I posted here is that I don't have the data to connect the papers. I only have the individual papers and their DOI. Usually online tools (often known to this space) is able to take the DOI and use that to identify papers and what they are connected to.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what you're asking, then? Are you looking for a data source of citations between papers indexed by DOI, for example?

Comment: This also seems to me like it's more of a ["content of research"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question.

Comment: I wouldn't say "content of research"; OP is not a graph theory researcher. Perhaps borderline "boat programming", since cluster-finding is a broader problem than just academia. But I know a lot of ML work has been done on citation graphs, etc., so it's possible there is an academia-specific software tool out there.

Comment: I think if you just take out the "tool for analyzing" it's an on-topic question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Co-citation analysis of my library?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/170930/co-citation-analysis-of-my-library)

Comment: Related publication: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-34/issue-2/The-Importance-of-Being-Clustered--Uncluttering-the-Trends-of/10.1214/18-STS686.full